# Formato de fecha

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un problema y espero me puedan ayudar, tengo una fecha con este formato `Tue Apr 20 2021 16:01:09 GMT-0500` (hora de verano central) pero necesito convertirla a `20-Abr-2021 04:01:09pm` en javascript.

Espero y me puedan ayudar.

Saludos.

Comment: Que has intentado hasta ahora? Podrías incluir tu código en la pregunta?

Comment: ¿La _fecha_ que tienes, es una cadena de caracteres, o es una fecha de tipo `Date`?

Comment: Es lo que viene desde mi base de datos.